# Proposition $3.4$ of Mean curvature flow with surgeries of two–convex hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, mean-curvature-flows

I'm studying by myself "[Mean curvature flow with surgeries of two–convex hypersurfaces](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00222-008-0148-4.pdf)" and I'm trying understand the last three lines of the proof of the proposition $3.4$ on page $149$:

> Then it follows easily that $M$ is a graph over this sphere with the desired
>   properties since the extrinsic curvature and its derivatives up to order $k$
>   control the function $u$ and its derivatives up to order $k + 2$.

My doubts are

1. Why $M$ is a graph over the sphere constructed in the proof?
2. How control $u$ based on the condition of the $(\varepsilon,k)$-parallelism? I can see how to do this control for its derivatives using the mean value theorem which can be read on page $71$ of "Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian geometry" by Thierry Aubin, but I can't use this theorem to control $u$.

Thanks in advance!